# Get VertexSize of Instance in VertexShader

Tags: unity, hlsl, procedural-generation, compute-shader

I'm using Unitys `DrawProceduralIndirect` function to directly render the content of a ComputeShader.

I setup the argumentBuffer for this function as follows:

```
    int[] csArgs = new int[] { ptsOnLine, 2, 0, 0};
    argsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(4, 4, ComputeBufferType.IndirectArguments);
```

So every instance consists of ptsOnLine (lets say 10) vertices.

My vertexShader then looks like this:

```
fsInput vert(uint id : SV_VertexID, uint instanceId : SV_InstanceId)
{
    fsInput fsIn;
    float3 worldPos = linePoints[id + (instanceId * 10)];
    fsIn.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, float4(worldPos, 1.0f));
    return fsIn;
}
```

The question is simple. My problem is: `(instanceId * 10)`. Is there a built in variable telling me the length of one instance? I couldn't find anything. I mean, its in the argument buffer so it shouldn't be too much of a problem? I could forward this value from the compute buffer but thats ugly. :)

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "built in" variable is contained in the args buffer.

From the unity docs "Buffer with arguments, bufferWithArgs, has to have four integer numbers at given argsOffset offset: **vertex count per instance**, instance count, start vertex location, start instance location."

So make sure you pass that argsBuffer to your shader and then use the first index.

Comment: Feels a bit redundant to pass it explicitly to the shader when it is already passed to `DrawProceduralIndirect`. Nevertheless, it seems that there is no built in variable, so this is the way to go. Thanks a lot!